# Is it possible to save options for a specific category in the WordPress Customizer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WordPress Customizer and I'd like to add options for categories, for instance "category background image", and so in the Customizer you go on Category X in the preview, you then set the category background option to be "red", and you then navigate to Category Y in the preview, and using the same option you can set it to be "blue" for this particular category. And the idea is you could do this with unlimited categories, so they can all have different background colors.

Is this possible? I know you can use the `active_callback` to make options in the customizer itself appear/disappear depending on where you are (i.e on a category page), but can you make options save an array with the current category ID seen in the preview + a value?

Comment: I wouldn't add this to customizer, but in the category taxonomy page. I made a tutorial on how to add page content to a certain category, but you could add images and colors the same way (just use input fields with upload image button that will call wp.media or wp.colorpicker)

Comment: I think you're right. Please submit this as an answer, as this is the correct way in WordPress' customizer current form.

Comment: It's a variation of this tutorial: http://madebydenis.com/adding-page-content-to-your-category-page/ I added the dropdown pages, but you can replace this with image picker, and color picker easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all your options and use the `active_callback` parameter on the parent sections. In your `active_callback` function you could have something like `return(is_category(Category ID, name, slug, or array of Category IDs, names, and/or slugs))`.

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean by Customizer is just a style customizer, I had an issue before where style should be changed according to a specific action and what I ended up doing is writing a php code that will generate css file which is imported in style.css
something like this:

```
$style='.';
$style.=get_selected_category_Id().'{';
$style.='color:'.get_selected_color().'}';
```

etc...
I know it is not a very good solution, but if you need this module for just one or if you do not have much time, it might work well for you